# FFMPEG Raw Video Restreaming

Tags: video, ffmpeg, raw, yuv

I captured raw video (yuv 4:2:0) from network and now trying to resend it.

`ffmpeg -f rawvideo -v info -pixel_format yuv420p -video_size 1240x1024 -framerate 25 -i out.raw udp://225.0.1.115:5000`

but the output is;

`[NULL @ 0x3cc5fc0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'udp://225.0.1.115:5000'`

i could not solve what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

udp is just a transport protocol; for output to network URL, you still have to set output format. In this case, it's`-f rawvideo`. ffmpeg only guesses output format if a file extension is recognized.

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pixel_format yuv420p -video_size 1240x1024 -framerate 25 -i out.raw -f rawvideo udp://225.0.1.115:5000
```

Ensure your receiver is ready to work with rawvideo with correct parameters.

Comment: thank you Gyan, it works.